# Rollup multi file output name

Tags: rollup, rollup-multi-entry

I am trying to rollup a number of js files and output to a single file with given name. I have the following **rollup.config.js** which works fine. The output file is built into the **build** folder, but it has the name **multi-entry.js**.

```
import { createBasicConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';
import dynamicImportVars from '@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars';
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import multi from '@rollup/plugin-multi-entry';

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({
    developmentMode: false,
    outputDir: "build"
});

export default merge(baseConfig, {
    input: ['src/*.js'],
    plugins: [
        multi(),
        dynamicImportVars(),
    ],
});
```

I have tried many variations such as:

```
const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({
    developmentMode: false,
    output: "build/bundle.js"
});
```

This creates **multi-entry.js** in **dist** folder.

```
const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({
    developmentMode: false,
    entryFileName: "bundle.js"
});
```

This creates **multi-entry.js** in **build** folder.

```
const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({
    developmentMode: false,
    outputDir: "build",
    output: {entryFileNames: "bundle.js"}
});
```

This creates **multi-entry.js** in **build** folder.

Any pointers?